# show explicit content of an xml file with a datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Currently not all information of the xml is displayed in my DataGridView. My question now is, how can I determine or filter the contents of the lines so that only the required information is displayed? Thanks in advance.

This is my actual code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace Moritz_WinFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlReader xmlFile;
                xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"xmlfile.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ReadXml method only captures four levels of xml tags.  After that you get multiple datatables that are fragmented and cannot be recombined.  The root level xml tag is the dataset name.  Then the next level tags are the datatables.  The third level tags become the column names of the tables.  The fourth level is the row data.  After that the data is fragmented into pieces that do not combine.  I usually use XDocument (xml linq) to parse complex xml files or use xml serialization.